# Use a partial in a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a Rails newbie, so bear with me.

I have a few places, some pages, some partials that use:

```
<%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete,
                                 data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                 title: post.content %>
```

Would it make sense to make this a partial since it is used repeatedly, sometimes in other partials too?

Is it o.k. to put partials in partials?

Answer (score 3):

I would try and limit the use of partials within other partials, since it can negatively affect view rendering speed (i.e. rendering lots of partials is super slow), but that said, I have to say, yes it is okay to use partials within other partials.

A couple things you should probably realize about this:

1. It can get confusing as all hell, especially when:

   - you're passing around a lot of local variables.
   - you're rendering collections, i.e. looping over a partial with an array of some sort.
2. Inferring from the fact that you're asking this question, you probably don't know that you're already rendering partials within partials.

   - what I mean by this, is that the layout (presumably "application.html.erb") is really going to be your only non-partial in a view.
   - Whenever you have an action rendered by a view, i.e. 'show', 'new', 'edit' (assuming you're rest-ful), you should realize that the corresponding view (i.e. 'show.html.erb' for example) is a partial being rendered within the main layout file.
   - Therefore any use of a partial that you yourself make ('_users.html.erb' or what have you) is actually already a 'partial within another partial'.

Kinda feels like Inception, doesn't it? :)

---

As for your specific example, I agree with the other answerer that you should probably just use it as a helper. And you can use it across many models so long as you abstract enough of the stuff away in the helper, like so:

```
def delete_link_for(polymorphic_object, method_symbol)
   link_to "delete", polymorphic_object, method: :delete,
                             data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                             title: post.send(method_symbol)
end
```

That way you can invoke like this:

```
 <%= delete_link_for(@post, :content) %>
 <%= delete_link_for(@user, :username) %>
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think a template is overkill for such a small smippet.  I would write a [helper method](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/49-using-helper-methods-in-ruby-on-rails) instead.

Comment: The helper method is a good idea, but this snippet is in several different models so I think it would be too confusing to do it that way.

Comment: You can have helpers at the application level.  One thing about RoR is that you never have to duplicate code.